# How to separate updating CVE database from scanning in owasp dependency check Maven plugin?

Tags: maven, jenkins-pipeline, owasp

I have a pom.xml with an OWASP dependency check profile:

```
    <!-- Profile to run owasp security checks. To activate, use -Dowasp=true -->
    <profile>
      <id>owasp-security-checks</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>owasp</name>
          <value>true</value>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <!-- Tests for vulnerabilities in dependencies. -->
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.owasp</groupId>
            <artifactId>dependency-check-maven</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.4</version>
            <configuration>
              <skipProvidedScope>true</skipProvidedScope>
              <skipRuntimeScope>true</skipRuntimeScope>
              <!--  Fail on high or critical severity -->
              <failBuildOnCVSS>7</failBuildOnCVSS> <!-- None (0), Low (0.1-3.9), Medium (4.0-6.9), High (7.0-8.9), and Critical (9.0-10.0) -->
            </configuration>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>check</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
```

This works as expected when executed with

```
sh 'mvn clean verify -U -Dowasp=true -DskipTests'
```

However, the plugin checks if the CVE database needs to be updated, and this sometimes fails. I want to separate the database update from the scanning, so I can run the update once a day at a specific time. Another advantage would be that, with different Jenkins jobs for updating and scanning, it would be easier to differentiate between update problems and scan issues.

However, I seem unable to find instruction how to do this, or (probably) I'm looking in the wrong place.

Comment: `mvn dependency-check:update-only` from projects directory or `mvn org.owasp:dependency-check-maven:7.4.4:update-only` from anywhere

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov And set `<auto-update>false</auto-update>` in the pom.xml?